# python ip address frequency scanner

Tags: python, sorting, ip

I am trying to create a programme that will scan a log. The most freqeunt address in the log is then displayed. That is it but i need a bit of help with it please...

```
 def analyse_logs():
open File = open('text.txt', "r")

readLines = openFile.read()
# pat = re.compile("^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$")
wordfreq = {}

for word in readLines.split():
    if word not in wordfreq:
        wordfreq[word] = 1
    else:
        wordfreq[word] += 1

print(wordfreq)

def extract_ip():
for line in string:
    line = line.rstrip()
    result = pattern.search(line)


 def most_frequent():
counter = 0
num = List[0]

for i in List:
    curr_frequency = List.count(i)
    if (curr_frequency > counter):
        counter = curr_frequency
        num = i

return num

 def main():


 if__name__=="_main_":
```

Comment: What does the log file look like?

Comment: 172.16.10.67 - - [03/Sep/2018:11:34:45] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437
172.16.10.101 - - [03/Sep/2018:11:34:45] GET /index.html HTTP/1.1 200 437

Comment: Its a .txt file with a lot of ip addresses

Comment: It would be helpful if you use correct indentations in the code. It is quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sorting(filename):
    infile = open(filename)
    ip_addr = []
    for line in infile:
        temp = line.split()
    for i in temp:
        ip_addr.append(i)
    infile.close()
    ip_addr.sort()
    outfile = open("result.txt", "w")
    for i in ip_addr:
        outfile.writelines(i)
    outfile.writelines(" ")
    outfile.close()
    sorting("sample_log_1.txt")

    ip_count_dict = {}
    ip_list = ['1.1.1.1', '1.1.1.2', '1.1.1.3', '1.1.1.1']
    # Loop and count ips

    # Final version of ip_count_dict {'1.1.1.1':2 , '1.1.1.2':1, '1.1.1.3':1}
```

I thought this might be easier